# some Exceptional Error

Tags: python, string, dictionary

hey i have written this python code.

```
str="abc def abc def abc def abc"
str=str.split(" ")
dict={0:'word'}
count=0
temp_list=[]
temp_list1=[]
for i in str:
   dict[str.count(i)]=i

for key,values in dict.items():
   print(key,values)
```

o/p:0 word
3 def
4 abc

that is okay but when i try to give this string,

```
str="abc def abc def"
str=str.split(" ")
dict={0:'word'}
count=0
temp_list=[]
temp_list1=[]
for i in str:
   dict[str.count(i)]=i

for key,values in dict.items():
   print(key,values)
```

o/p:
0 word
2 def

where 2 abc value is missing from the output.

Comment: Don't shadow important keywords like `str` and `dict` by creating variables with the same name.

Comment: Change;  {0:'word'} >  {'word': 0}, then   def 3 abc 4 .. Using your method, the key 2 is being replaced by last occurrence of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. `{2: "def", 2: "abc"}` is impossible output. If you're trying to make a histogram, you should be aiming for `{"def": 2, "abc": 2}`. It seems like you've got keys and values mixed up.

Try using `collections.Counter`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> str="abc def abc def"
>>> d = Counter(str.split())
>>> d
Counter({'abc': 2, 'def': 2})
```